# Sublime Text 3 compile and run (in terminal) C on OS X with passed arguments

Tags: c, macos, gcc, build, sublimetext3

I'm trying to compile a C program in Sublime Text 3 then run it in the terminal (which opens up through Sublime Text) on OS X Yosemite. My build system is:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c",

    "variants":
    [
        {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "gcc '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I build, for example, `test.c`, it compiles fine. When I run the program I get this: `bash: line 1: 916 Segmentation fault: 11`. I'm sure this is because my program needs arguments passed to it.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I change the build system so that when I run it, it opens up the terminal and runs in there?
2. How do I pass arguments to the program before it runs? For example, on Linux I would type `./test hello 20932aa` and it will run fine. How can I achieve the same on Sublime Text 3 (OS X Yosemite).

Comment: OS X also has terminal. You can use that if you want.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want Sublime Text to open it up when I build the code. It's one less extra step I would have to do.

Comment: i don't know if you can pass a different argument in each run, but in the same build file as above you can especify an argunment, as an example" in the last line (the last cmd) you can write: "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "gcc '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name} hello 20932aa'"].

Comment: @JordyBaylac That ends up saying no directory is named `test hello 20932aa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need in your build system to compile and run C code in ST3. Just replace **arg1 arg2 arg3** with your arguments and save your build system before you use `Tools -> Build` on your C program like usual.

The `&&` operator allows you to execute another `"shell_cmd"` (shell command) after the operator.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name} arg1 arg2 arg3"
}
```

Alternatively, here is a build system with all the bells and whistles.

```
{
    "shell_cmd" : "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}",
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name} arg1 arg2 arg3"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want your program to open in a new terminal window, use this build system. You won't be able to pass arguments to it though.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make ${file_base_name} && open -a Terminal.app ${file_path}/${file_base_name}",
}
```